# Deegree installation / getting started

Tags: installation, deegree

I've just tried to set up Deegree on the server with Tomcat7 servlet by copying the WAR file to the webapps folder as described in the [documentation](http://download.deegree.org/documentation/3.3.14/html/installation.html#downloading). So now I can use the interface on the port `localhost:8080/deegree-webservices-3.3.14`. It is also indicated on the interface that the working directory is `/usr/share/tomcat7/.deegree`.
However, when I try to set the pw or load a workspace, I got the error notification that this folder doen't exist. Seemingly, no folder has been set anywhere on the server.

Should I do anything else to install Deegree properly?

Answer (score 1):

As I'm a newbie to server configuration I didn't ask google the right question a couple of days ago. But now...

The question was already answered in an other forum, so if you have the same problem:
https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/issues/510